# How to create folder and upload file using Rest api and oauth2.0

Tags: c#, java, rest, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I want to create a folder and upload files using rest api
 my code is like this

```
  public string CreateFolder(string FolderName)
    {
        int WorkSpaceId = 330201;
        int id = 168079105;
        var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Session["tokenSession"];
        var request = WebRequest.Create(RequestProfileUrl + FolderName);
        request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        request.Method = "POST";
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("" + request.RequestUri);
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            return responseText;
        }
    }
```

I have to do like this

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

{
    "name": "My example folder"
}`
```

I added request header and content-type, I don't know how to add `name` parameter to my request.

Comment: Why is `Java` tagged?

Comment: I have problem with oauth2.0 and rest api so i added java also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the body of your POST request  you need to get the request stream first, and then write to it. See the sample code below. Note that I changed the Content-Type from "multipart/form-data" to "application/json" as this is what your data seems to be.

```
       // String with the body content 
        string postBody = "{\"name\":\"myfoldername\"}";
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
        byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes (postBody);

        // Set Content type to application/json
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        // Set content length of the string being posted.
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

        // Get the request stream and write body bytes to it
        Stream newStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ();
        newStream.Write (byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
```